# Best way to implement modular approach - Refletion

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection

In my previous company, we implemented the modular approach via reflection, and all the infomration to attach the module with application was present in database. We just insert some scripts and it was ready to perform.

Foloowing are the key benifits of this implementation:

1. When a new module require to add, developer does not need to update
   the core code, becuase module was invoking via reflection
2. Once development of any module completes, we could easly plug or
   unplug that module withour deployment of any patch, becuase
   configuration was saved in database.
3. We can easly in-active or disable the buggy module.
4. All modules are independent of each other, we just need to copy
   required dll to deployemnt folder

Now I joined to another organization and want to implement modular approach. So before starting I just want to do some research, so my question is, **it was the best approach to implement the module? or there is another way exist to implement this approach?**

Comment: Reflection can be very heavy. I would take a look at Plug-in architecture where each module is implemented as a plug-in that may executes in its own app domain (crash-safe). There are .NET frameworks like MAF or MEF that support such an architecture. Or consider a micro services based application. A service based architecture where each module is deployed as a remote service even allows sharing of service instances. I think it really depends on the type of application and degree of required extensibility what is best suited. All this comes with a price, so you have to make sure it's worth it.

Comment: You are right, reflection can be very heavy, but I can cache the objects created from reflection rather than creating the objects every time through reflection. Further I will look into your suggested Plug-in Architecture. Thank you for your feedback.